# Neo4j Php Cypher Array

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher

I am currently attempting to create an array of key words (strings) that I can reference later in a query. I feel dumb posting this question however I feel I have searched all over and cannot find simple syntax for creating an array and then echoing back the values of the array.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

For a database consisting of the following data:

```
CREATE (:Person {name:'Alice'}), 
       (:Person {name:'Bob'}), 
       (:Person {name:'Charles'}), 
       (:Person {name:'Devin'})
```

Create an array called `names` that you reference within the query:

```
WITH ["Alice", "Bob", "Charles"] AS names
MATCH (n:Person)
WHERE n.name IN names
RETURN n
```

This returns the nodes for Alice, Bob, and Charles. Alternatively, you could refer to the elements in the array individually by `names[i]`.

Is this what you meant?